# Can we custom design a pkpass?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, passkit

I have a physical card and I want to design a pkpass which should look similar to it.

I am following this link - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW1 for the pass design and creation.

There it was given You can’t change pass styles or add new ones. I have searched for the custom design of pass but in vain. Does anyone know how to custom design a pass? Please help me if you know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the documentation says that you can't change the fundamental design of a `PassKit` card, then it's clearly not supported. Apple has strict rules for their UI design.